# how to pass object of person item recycler view to anthor activity

Tags: android

I start send data from on clic item recyclerview for all my person list but i need to use some information in activity 2 i just pass the name of person

Nb :  person object (id,name,phone,email,post)

this is code of click item recycler view adapter

@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

```
                final Intent intent;

                intent =  new Intent(context, Details_Employee.class);
                employee.set
                intent.putExtra("name",name.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("post",post.getText().toString());
                /*intent.putExtra("dept",dept.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("codebadge",badge.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("mobile",phone.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
```

*/
                    context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: First make Person class Parsable or Serializable and put inside your intent

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getExtras()` method of intent class in Activity 2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String post= intent.getStringExtra("post");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make your person object implement `Serializable` (or `Parcelable`).

Then, pass it to the intent like you added the other data:

```
intent.putExtra("person", person);
```

Comment: how to retrive the name of the person and all information !!

Comment: @joker_7 `Person person = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("person");`

Comment: when i need to work with the name of person
i do somthing like this ?? 

name=person.getName();
?

Comment: @joker_7 Yes :)

Comment: In Activity i do 
Employee employee = (Employee) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("person");

        Toast.makeText(Details_Employee.this, "Name of item is  "+employee.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

in my adapter class

itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    final Intent intent;

                    intent =  new Intent(context, Details_Employee.class);
                    intent.putExtra("person", employee);

Comment: @joker_7 in `setOnClickListener()` you need to call `startActivity(intent);` as well.